Low throughput received when i run my test via jenkins
There is a jenkins job that runs my jmeter script on a machine to fetch the throughput. When i run the test via jenkins pipeline, i see that the test outputs very less throughput.Whereas if i run jmeter script on the local machine i get a good throughput. Both the jenkins and jmeter machine are on the same network with the same specs.
I have tried to restart the jenkins on the slave and as well as the master and then run the tests, still the same behavior is observed

Given you're running the same JMeter test using the same (or 100% similar) JMeter instance with the same configuration you should get the same (or similar) results.
You can try out the following:

Compare jmeter.log files from both local and Jenkins slave
Check resources utilization on Jenkins slave, you can use Agent Status or JMeter PerfMon Plugin for this
Operating system on Jenkins slave side might require extra tuning in terms of kernel TCP/IP parameters

